# Все про тот же пароль на Линукс

Tags: пароль, linux

Пароль на root нашли, сменили. Но загружается все равно из-под user. Дальше-то что? Пожалуйста, допомогите.

Comment: Вы уж расскажите что не работает или не удобно ?... Linux все по дефолту под юзером работают.

Answer (score 2):

Он и должен загружаться под юзером. Пароль администратора - только для особых случаев. Как бы не винда нифига. В консоли можно попробовать su (если установлен). Либо можно включить пользователя в группу администраторов (wheel вроде бы), но root в unixlike OS - это святое.Может какой-то конкретный вопрос есть? Постоянно вводить пароль надоедает или установить что-то не можете?

Answer (score 0):

В linux вроде где-то есть в настройках вибрать авто вход под рутом!!!или только так sudo -s

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите запустить программу в рутовом режиме в gnome, то (в ubuntu) набираеш клавиши ALT+F2 и открывается окно ввода команд (аналог "Выполнит" в винде). Там набираем последовательность gksu <команда> . Т.е. "gksu" это аналог "su" , тока в оконном режиме работы )))

А вот под рутом постоянно сидеть не стоит, можно всю операционку по глупости попортить...